# TCLAP: how to check whether an optional command line argument has been specified?

Tags: c++, command-line

How do I check in the [Templatized C++ Command Line Parser Library](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/) library whether an optional `ValueArg` has been specified on the command line? I went through the source code, but did not find anything to that end...

Comment: I assume you mean the [Templatized C++ Command Line Parser Library](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: You assumed correctly. I updated the question to be explicit.

Comment: You mean like the [Arg::isSet](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/html/classTCLAP_1_1Arg.html#a6af7a1e92b5d92fc2d90c1a95aab4384) method?

Comment: @Useless Yes! (don't know how I missed it) Please make it a reply, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bool TCLAP::Arg::isSet () const](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/html/classTCLAP_1_1Arg.html#a6af7a1e92b5d92fc2d90c1a95aab4384) method to do this. From the docs, it:

> Indicates whether the argument has already been set.
>
> Only true if the arg has been matched on the command line.